# strut 1 : Actionforward to forward back to calling view with same ActionForm

Tags: struts-1

I have application in struts 1.

In this I have mailing form (to , from , subject , body etc) after user filling up the form . calls the action (press send button ) which will get the data from Form and send the mail

Here when mailing fails I have to send back the user to same mailing form with same data entered by him (i.e.., same ActionForm )

Can some one please help me how to achieve this in Struts 1

Answer (score 0):

This should help you get started.

In the struts configuration file, the page gets redirected to the "input" attribute value if it fails, in this example "email.jsp" page.

**Struts config file:**

```
<struts-config>
        <form-beans>
        <form-bean name="emailForm" type="com.EmailForm">
       </form-bean>
    </form-beans>
    <action path="/sendEmail"
        type="com.SendEmailAction"
        scope="request" name="mailForm" 
        input="email.jsp"
        parameter="getCgrs">
        <forward name="success" path="email.jsp"></forward>
    </action>
</struts-config>
```

**Your jsp Page:**

```
<html:form action="/sendEmail" >
   <html:text property = "toEmail" />
   <input type="submit" value="Send Email"/>
</html:form>
```

In your form class you should have a property "toEmail" that matches the property in your jsp page.

```
public class EmailForm extends ActionForm{
    private String toEmail;
    public void setToEmail(String toEmail){
         this.toEmail = toEmail;
    }
    public String getToEmail(){
         return toEmail;
    }
}
```

Comment: You missed the most important part: [ActionMapping.getInputForward()](http://struts.apache.org/release/1.3.x/apidocs/org/apache/struts/action/ActionMapping.html#getInputForward%28%29)

Comment: This is returning the control back to required calling JSP  but , I also want the data with which it was submitted.Like to , cc, bcc which are been provided by user  in the form